# How do I remove smoke odor from a console?

Tags: hardware

I recently bought a used Xbox One. It works great with no problems, but even after a month, both the console itself and the controllers have a noticeable odor of cannabis smoke. Nobody here smokes, so I presume the odor is from a previous owner.

How can I clean my console and controllers so as to remove the smoke odor without damaging them? I unplugged the console, removed the batteries from the controllers, and wiped them down with a tissue slightly damp with soap and water, but this did not help much, if at all. I did notice that the odor appears to be emanating mostly from orifices, especially ports.

While my problem is specifically with an Xbox One, I presume that the answer will be similar or identical for similar consoles which have both sensitive electronics and moving parts, such as PlayStation 4 or Nintendo Wii.

Please, no jokes about getting a high score.

Comment: Any way you can return it? It's probably going to be more work than it's worth to clean it. At the very least I'd check the circuit board of everything to see if there's resin stinking it up, and that sounds like a lot of work

Comment: also worth considering if you want to take it apart. https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Xbox+One+Teardown/19718 ifixit has a good guide, and you can/should consider cleaning out the inside if its anything is vile as cigarette smoke and you can spot test and clean different parts of the system differently.

Comment: Might be more fitting on Lifehacks.SE though.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things you can try here. Each one increasing the, uh, danger of damage... but all are safe if done correctly. With all of them ensure the system is completely unplugged and all that.

1. **Air it out** - As you say you've had it for around a month so this one may not work as well, but just opening it up best you can and leaving it out by a breezy window or fan can help odors dissipate naturally.
2. **Air it out... harder** - Use a can of compressed air and blast it into things like the ports and intake/out take fans. Be careful not to spray too hard/long and damage parts, though.
3. **Vinegar solution** - You've already done a soap and water solution, but soap isn't exactly what you use to attack the stinky. Vinegar is better. Use equal parts Vinegar and Water and lightly wet a cotton swab or cloth and carefully wipe the troublesome areas. A Q-tip can help reach into the various ports. Be **very** careful around circuit boards. Use a clean dry cloth or hair dryer set on cool mode only to completely dry out areas you've cleaned to avoid moisture damage.
4. **Baking Soda/Charcoal/Coffee Grinds** - if a "wet" cleaning isn't doing it, let's go dry. Baking Soda and Charcoal are phenomenal odor absorbers and coffee has its own way of overpowering stinks with its own, more pleasant (to many) stink. You want your odor absorber of choice in a container with vents so air can flow in and out, but not the material itself([here's an example of one such product](https://a.co/d/6tQTslh)). Put the odor absorber in an airtight container. Now Put the offensive smelling device in that same airtight container and let it work. This can take days to even weeks depending on how bad everything is, but it will eventually always do the trick. The danger here is just the time it takes and you have to be **extra** careful to not allow the odor absorber into the device as that will create its own new dilemma.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it might be good to add rubbing alcohol as something to try as well before going too extreme.  AFAIK it doesn't pose much threat to turned off electronics, evaporates easily, and in my experience rubbing alcohol actually removes cannabis residue, which is basically ignored by water.

Comment: @JMac I was thinking about trying some isopropyl alcohol too.  My first thought though was its not good for plastics (I think I once heard this?), though a short exposure to it should be ok regardless.  You'll want to use the highest concentration you can get (91% I believe is commonly found in drug stores in the U.S.). And you want a newer-ish bottle, since it does break down into water overtime if not stored right/old, which can be bad for electronics obviously!